# Eclipse - step filter for Launcher.class?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

When debugging I step in the [Launcher](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/457575/) and I get

> The source attachment does not contain the source for the file Launcher.class

My question is how can I filter the launcher class from my debugging settings. I added the class in Java > Debug > Step Filtering but I still step in !

[image]

As you see I added it twice - still no joy. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug - any workarounds then ?

Comment: are you got the solution for that ?

Comment: @Rcs: I ahave no solution - I would have posted it here :)

Comment: i supposed that you are forget or something Thank you.